# variable assignment open_form() codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

just a simple question, can we assigned codeigniter `open_form()` to javascript `var`?

i have a code like this:

```
var openForm = '<?php echo form_open("controller/some_function", 
array('class' => 'class_name', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>';
```

but when i run it, i got error in my console saying:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

but, when i try this:

```
var closeForm = '<?php echo form_close(); ?>';
```

it didn't show any error.

though i guess it's not about syntax error, i still have no idea what is wrong and what happens. can anyone explain?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here? Do you want dynamically append HTML or codeigniter form somewhere?

Comment: @ShrikantMavlankar yeah, dynamically append html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use like this

```
var openForm = `<?php echo form_open("controller/some_function", array("class" => "class_name", "enctype" => "multipart/form-data")); ?>`;

openForm += '<?php echo form_close(); ?>';

$("#your_element)id").html(openForm);
```

In javascript You can't split a string across multiple lines. `<?php echo form_open(); ?>` add `\n` at the end which create Syntax error.

As well `<?php echo form_open(); ?>` adds double quotes, which also ends into escaping issues.

To avoid issues In such cases you can use the template literals which is **`**

For more details you can visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal) site.
I hope it justifies your query.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please up vote and accept my answer? :)

Comment: Yes. **`** is called back-tick where as **'** is called as single quote. Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick where as strings can be  enclosed with single quote or double quote.